# CasperJS from Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, casperjs

I've just installed node.js, python, casperjs and slimerjs. Not sure if relevant, but I initially used:

```
npm install capserjs
```

and

```
npm install slimerjs
```

(without the -g flag)

I've since uninstalled both and reinstalled using -g.

When I type "casperjs" from the Windows command prompt, it appears to work fine. However, I prefer to use Cygwin. Typing in "casperjs" from Cygwin yields the following message:

Can't open '/cygdrive/c/[pwd path]/C:\Users[my user]\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js'

...where [pwd path] is whatever directory I happen to be in at the time, and [my user] is my Windows username.

The above suggests it's trying to use $AppData as the root of the path, but for some reason it's also appending the present working directory. When I installed these on another laptop before I tried this one, I didn't experience this problem.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?